# Why do we calculate success rate with 1 - p like methods?

Tags: probability

If treatment A has 60% success rate and treatment B has 90% success rate, then is B 4x times more successful (1-0.6)/(1-0.9) or 1.5x (0.9/0.6) compared to A?

I'd say 4x, but what makes us calculate the non-(non-success) rate in this case?

Comment: Where have you seen such comparison?

Comment: I am trying to compare it myself, in terms of a terminal disease's treatment. In this case it is normal to think in survival rates and not success rates, right?

Comment: Well, maybe it's better to be as clear as possible. If you have method A with $60~\%$ success rate and method B with $90~\%$ success rate, perhaps it's best to just say
$$
\text{Method B has one-fourth of the failure rate of method A}
$$
This way, everyone will know what it means.